# Random elusive and sudden redirects to AccessDenied.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, sharepoint-permissions

A strange bug annoys some of our users. If the browser opened any page of any lib of any SPWeb and keeps it open for some time (10+ minutes) sometimes it redirects the user to  AccessDenied.aspx page of the same SPWEb.

Definitely user has access rights and reopening of pages works fine.

The error gives us the correlation id and...well...log only shows info that there was an error with such correlation id.

At first, I thought that it may be caused by a broken permission setting and restored them via  /_layouts/15/permsetup.aspx but now I see that SPWebs with normal permission settings give the same error.

Any ideas, on where else I should dig?
Thanks.

Comment: Whic kind of customization you have in your site, also did you face the same behaviour for any new site?

Comment: Hi, Mohamed!
If you mean SPWeb, some of sites that gave us such errors are quite new. Common customization for all of them is that permissions inheritance from root SPWeb was disabled  and  special SPGroups were added to Visitors, Members and Owners.  
Tree view enabled  for main page and couple of classic DocLib webparts added.
Nothing more.